# How to update user password with the file has password,without prompt key in?

Tags: linux, sudo, passwd, shadow

I am using Debian 11,set password with `shadow`.
I random generate password into file `pas`:

```
cat pas
"Th3P@ssw0rd"
```

When I update password to normal user has `sudo` privilege,
`sudo passwd username`

I always copy and paste `Th3P@ssw0rd` from file `pas`.

How to update user password with the file has password,without prompt key in?

Comment: [Using the passwd command from within a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/714915/4023950)

Answer (score 1):

Set the password of `username` to `Th3P@ssw0rd`:

```bsh
echo 'username:Th3P@ssw0rd' | sudo chpasswd
```

Set the password using `pas` file:

```bsh
echo "username:$(cat pas)" | sudo chpasswd
```